# Group the data by column and obtain the mean of the rest of the variables in R

Tags: r

[image: The dataset is shown as follows, with quantitative and qualitative variables]

In total I have 21k observations. In order to do a cluster analysis, I would like to group the 21K observations by the column "Neighborhood" (there are a total of 140 neighborhoods). So I would like to group by "neighborhood" and get the mean of the quantitative variables for each neighborhood (e.g. "buy price") and the mode for the qualitative variables (e.g. "energy certificate", "has parking", etc).
So that the dataset is simply 140 rows (neighborhoods) and their means and modes depending on the variable concerned.
I hope someone can help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Screenshots of your dataset won't help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll emulate with `mtcars` and `dplyr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
quant <- c("mpg", "disp", "hp")
qual <- c("vs", "am", "gear")

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(across(quant, mean), across(qual, ~ names(sort(table(.),decreasing=TRUE))[1]))
# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#     cyl   mpg  disp    hp vs    am    gear 
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     4  26.7  105.  82.6 1     1     4    
# 2     6  19.7  183. 122.  1     0     4    
# 3     8  15.1  353. 209.  0     0     3
```

The `names(table(.))[1]` is meant to be your "mode" of a qualitative variable. We can validate that it is doing what we expect with a quick table:

```r
xtabs(~cyl+vs, data=mtcars)
#    vs
# cyl  0  1
#   4  1 10
#   6  3  4
#   8 14  0
xtabs(~cyl+am, data=mtcars)
#    am
# cyl  0  1
#   4  3  8
#   6  4  3
#   8 12  2
xtabs(~cyl+gear, data=mtcars)
#    gear
# cyl  3  4  5
#   4  1  8  2
#   6  2  4  1
#   8 12  0  2
```

showing that for gear 4, 6, and 8, respectively, the most common `vs` is `1`, `1`, and `0`; for `am`: `1`, `0`, and `0`; for `gear`: `4`, `4`, and `3`. Those correspond to the values in the return above.

In your case, change `cyl` to `neighborhood`, and make sure your `qual` and `quant` have the desired variables listed.

Comment: Incredible maestro, thank you very much :))